# PHP file does not execute JavaScript XMLHttpRequest after receiving a webhook but does in browser

Tags: javascript, php, webhooks, trello

I set up a [Trello webhook](https://developers.trello.com/page/webhooks) that sends a POST request to mywebsite.com/webhook.php every time an action is taken within my Trello board. Right now, my goal when receiving these requests is simply to use [Trello's REST API](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#introduction) (for now just manually inputting the key and token) to create a list in my Trello board just to verify that I'm able to do so. What I have in my webhook.php file is the following:

```
<?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();',
     "xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.trello.com/1/lists?name=[NAME]&idBoard=[ID]&key=[KEY]&token=[TOKEN]');",
     'xhr.send();',
     '</script>';
?>
```

The problem is that while this works if I simply enter in the URL mywebsite.com/webhook.php in my browser, it doesn't work when called from the Trello webhook (I've verified that the webhook is actually being received). I tested the URL in Postman and it returns 200 status but it similarly doesn't actually create a list in Trello.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear. It's not PHP that execute JavaScript, the browser does that.

Comment: What is this? `name=[NAME]` Did you replace name with something.

Comment: [NAME] refers to what I want the new list to be called; in the actual code, I replaced all the brackets with proper values.

Comment: @AlanBi PHP only gives back HTML and does not execute your JavaScript. Javascript can be executed by your Browser or you have to use nodeJS (Server Side JavaScript). But PHP is defintly not what you need to use in your case

Comment: Show us how you replace that then. We want the real proper code not some clues to what your code looks like

Comment: Make the POST request using PHP. (Research this if you don’t know how, it has been discussed enough times already.)